# What is the most efficient way in doing file operations in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

What is the most efficient way in doing file operations in PHP,

Add / Edit / Delete files and Directory using PHP.

I have created a file manager using CI's FTP Class, i just want to know if what i am doing or the approach is right, or is using FTP functions not advisable ?

Thanks,

Comment: FTP for **local** files?

Comment: @zerkms yes, im using local at the moment

Comment: using FTP for local files is the most crazy thing I've heard ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it much secured as mentioned here.
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/151532/

Otherwise, CI has its own security classes. You can use them to make secured file access to users.